# Ejecutar comandos de host real desde contenedor de docker

Tags: linux, docker, contenedores

tengo una duda a cerca de docker. Quiero crear una API que gestione un sistema Linux, para ello se ejecutarán comandos cómo: useradd, crontab, top, archivos del sistema... Para desplegar la aplicación se me ocurrió usar un contenedor de docker ya que la API requiere de dependencias como python y otros paquetes de Linux para obtener información del hardware. También porque será más fácil de desplegar en un servidor, sin embargo tengo un problema ya que necesito ejecutar comandos en la máquina real y me gustaría saber si hay manera de que ciertos comandos que se ejecuten en un contenedor afecten a la máquina real.

Comment: Tendrías que desplegar _algo_ en la máquina que permita ejecutar dichos comandos. Podría ser incluso Telnet o SSH. Pero, qué sentido tendría darle tantas vueltas, si el contenedor, entre otras cosas, sirve para crear un _sandbox_ dónde no afectes a la máquina real, en este caso no parece tener mucho sentido usar un contenedor, pues justamente quieres hacer lo contrario: si afectarla.

Comment: Quería hacerlo para tener las dependencias más centralizadas y no instalar muchos paquetes en la máquina real del usuario.